# Dependent pick list error in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning-out

I need to display more than 10 dependent Picklists on a Visualforce page, but when I add more than 10 I get the below error:

> Visualforce pages may not display more than 10 dependent picklists
>   together with their controlling fields. This includes any picklists in
>   components or inline pages.

Can someone please suggest if there is any workaround for the same? And also, if the same limitation exists for Aura components or LWC?